# "We were looking through all these pictures of little dogs." - Why is she saying "...all these...", despite not pointing to any pictures?

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, articles, idiomatic-language

A native English speaker says this sentence, when she mentions about how she got a dog for the first time:

**I wasn't sure, but we were looking through all these pictures of little dogs.** [Lady Barber](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QUej2pWLUUc) (see: 15:32-15:39)

The expression **"....all these pictures ......."** caught my attention, because when she is saying **"all these"**, she is not actually pointing to any pictures at that time, but she is talking about her life years ago.

However, in English classes, people are taught that **"these/all of these/all these** are used when you are pointing at something.

So, shortly, why does she say **"...all these..."** instead of saying **".....looking through pictures of ......"** (without **"all these"**)?

Comment: all these can also refer back in the text to something already mentioned. So, the pointing can be to something in a text, not in reality. But probably not here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In informal speech, **this** is sometimes used in place of the indefinite article to indicate that a thing being mentioned for the first time is important.

> I opened the front door and there was this man standing there...

So, in the plural, the speaker means **We were looking through some pictures** or perhaps, as she says '*all* these', **a lot of pictures.**

Comment: Yes. 'All these' can simply mean 'a lot' - _after the crash, the police asked me all these questions_. Often associated with impatience.

Comment: I think MH has hit the nail on the head.

Comment: +1. It's worth noting that we only use *this* this way when we don't expect the listener to already be familiar with the thing in question. When we *do* expect that (even tentatively), we instead use *that*: "You remember when we opened the front door and there was **that** man standing there?", or "It's like **that** old joke about [...]". (I think this is related to the physical/literal senses of "this" and "that", where we tend to use "this" for something in our own space and "that" for something in an shared space.)

Comment: @ruakh - Yes - that's why I specified 'the _indefinite_ article'.

Comment: @KateBunting: I did notice that, but it's not enough IMHO, because I think both of my examples allow "a" as an alternative to "that", but neither allows "this" as an alternative to "that". So the choice of "this" as opposed to "that" is stricter than the choice of "a" as opposed to "the".

Comment: Addendum: actually, sorry, my second example would really use "the" rather than "a". ("A" would be fine, but would have a different interpretation, and in that interpretation "this" *would* work.) But I stand by my first example.